# Knockout int value - display string

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

is it possible to display string value depend on int value ?

For example, I have an array observable list and one of the element is int. I don't want to display int, but depend on int value, string.

For example if I have 1 I want to display "one", 2 -> "other" and goes on.

Now I have:

```
<td data-bind="text: test_value"></td>
```

It is in foreach loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.

The simplest solution is to just do declare a lookup object and do the lookup in your binding binding:

```
<td data-bind="text: $root.strings[test_value]"></td>
```

Where view model has `strings` lookup object like this:

```
strings: {
    1: 'test',
    2: 'other',
    3: 'thrid'
}
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/zuq0whhw/.

Notes:

- because you are inside a foreach you need to use `$parent` or `$root` (depending on your setup) to access your lookup object which is presumable declared on a "higher level"
- if your `test_value` is a KO observable you need to write `$root.strings[test_value()]` because KO observables are functions and you need to invoke them without any arguments to get the underplaying value.

More complex and better maintainable solutions would be to use [computed properties](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) to do the lookup logic in your view model or create a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) which encapsulates this logic and then you can use it for any other property as well.

Comment: It's a little bit misunderstanding. I would like to have string value demand on int value, not concatenation. For exampl 1->"test", 2->"other" ...

Comment: @Cieja yes, your original example was very very misleading... you should update your question with this new example! see my update answer